# How to get variable out of Triggered function and into local variable without Permissions error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm setting up a Google Apps Script on a Google Sheet which extracts the value of the name of the parent folder of the sheet so that it can be inserted into the sheet using a function reference in a cell ( e.g. =ReturnParentFolderName() )

I've created a function which outputs the correct value of the parent folder name directly into a specific cell on the sheet (from within the function) but I keep getting permission errors when I try to use that (correct) value or variable outside of the function.

This function called GetFolderName() is set to run on open via a project trigger. (I did this so as to try and prevent premissions errors as apparently Project triggers have higher permissions.)

It seems that DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()); in my code triggers a permissions problem. I've tried running and authorising the script from within the Scripts interface (Run >Run Function) and also had a go at using callbacks but nothing i've tried has worked. Here's what I've got so far:

```
var CurrentfolderName;

function GetFolderName() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()); 
    var parentFolder = driveFile.getParents();
    CurrentfolderName = parentFolder.next().getName();

    // ss.getRange('C3!D2').setValue(CurrentfolderName);

}

function ReturnParentFolderName() {

    return CurrentfolderName;
}
```

I'm looking to have =ReturnParentFolderName() once entered into a cell on the sheet output the correct value of the parent folder name. Instead I get the following error: "Error
You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFileById. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) (line 18)."

I need a way to assign the value set by "var CurrentfolderName = parentFolder.next().getName();" within the GetFolderName() outside the function so it's useable in the sheet as a function reference. Since this function runs "On open" via a Project Trigger I'm not sure how to access that variable so it's useable only once it's been assigned and so that the permissions errors aren't triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of your global variable isn't retained from one execution to the other.

If you want to store values for later reuse, you should use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service).

E.g. this code does what I think you're trying to do, although you may have to grant additional permissions (can't compare with yours):

```js
function GetFolderName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()); 
  var parentFolder = driveFile.getParents();
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("parentname", parentFolder.next().getName());

}

function ReturnParentFolderName() {

    return PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("parentname");
}
```